# Error when releasing an atmosphere package for meteor

Tags: meteor

When I try the command :

```
mrt release https://github.com/f...
```

I obtain this error :

```
Adding tag and pushing repo

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/utils/git.js:37
      throw "Command exited: " + error;
                           ^
Command exited: Error: spawn ENOENT
```

I tryed to reinstall everything (git, meteor, mrt...). Not a clue ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide the local path of your package at the command-line, not the repository URL:

```
mrt release ./
```